# How does the Chrome Developer Tool "Properties" section help with CSS/JavaScript development?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, google-chrome, developer-tools

How does the Chrome Developer Tool "Properties" section help with CSS/JavaScript development?

In the screenshot it shows `blur`, `contains`, `focus`, etc.

I don't know what you can do with these.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's showing you exactly which JavaScript functions are included in that element's prototype (the functions that you can call on that element).

It helps when you're trying to figure out exactly how you can solve a specific problem but you're not sure exactly what JavaScript functions you have available to you.

Answer (score 2):

Speaking about css, i found the dev tool to be very very usefull. I use it to debug my css code and check whatever an element inherited a class that doesn't mean to be there.
I never used it for javascript code, except for random errors i couldn't solve by myself.